# How to force firefox to download a mp3 file (no audio/mp3 in the Type of content in apps in firefox settings)

Tags: firefox, audio, download, mp3

Good morning, superuser.com community, have a nice day

Please help me with this:
http: impossible to post :(

(image link above removed (it was impossible for me to put a link here. I can't understand what I did wrong))

I could download mp3 files directly to a folder until yesterday, and suddenly not anymore.

Look at the screenshot, there is no option like mp3 files, or audio files, mpeg / mp3 files, or anything like that.

How do I get something like "Mp3 files" to reappear in the content type section.

Until yesterday, that option appeared but it no longer appears.

my version of firefox is v65.0.2 (64-bit)
please not ask me to upgrade

And I already have media.play-stand-alone to false configured.

I need to be able to download audio files immediately to a folder instead of automatically playing them in firefox.
I use a "snap links" plugin to download massively, but now it doesn't work for me since that firefox option no longer appears to me, from one day to the next it disappeared.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNuiH.jpg

Answer (score 0):

`media.play-stand-alone` to false (as you already set)
and
`media.windows-media-foundation` set to it's default value.

Or simple use other download manager and download it by link.